# ImportError: Numpy when importing pandas in virtual environment

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, importerror

I am receiving a weird error, which I think is due to different python versions installed on my machine. I used Python 3.7 and Anaconda Python 3.6. In anaconda I set up a virtual environment which has pandas installed as a package. Nevertheless, I cannot load it as there is an error with numpy. I tried instaling/uninstalling the packages many times and also uninstalled and installed anaconda and python, but still the error occours.
I am working on windows 10.

This is the error

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
     import pandas as pd
     File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\freelancetrade\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
     "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
```

ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

This is the very basic code i am executing:

```
    import pandas as pd
    print("done")
```

As I mentioned I tried different solutions - but nothing helped so far. And also all packages are installed.
Any good idea to solve this?

Cheers Harry

Comment: You are either using pipenv or virtualenv, which has there own set of site-packages and are isolated from your pre installed anaconda packages. Try pip install numpy in you active virtual environment that should resolve your issue. If not its mostly due to multiple Python versions you are referring above.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I did right now was to downgrade Anaconda Python from 3.6.x to 3.5.x and all surprisingly everything works fine now... So in case anyone cannot import pandas because of numpy and getting the same error try to use another version of python.